# How do I restart apache as non-root (using a git-hook)?

Tags: permissions, root, apache-httpd, git, non-root-user

For one specific user I want to be able to restart Apache. This user does have sudo privileges and I could run `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`, but I want to include this restart script in a git post-receive hook. So this would prompt for the password and fail. So the question is: what is the proper way to allow this user to restart apache, without requiring sudo? I want to restrict option to only restarting Apache, and only this particular user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider using `sudo` with the `NOPASSWD` config.

See `man 5 sudoers`

Ex:

```
Host_Alias     LOCAL=192.168.0.1
user_foobar    LOCAL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2
```

Comment: You should consider `NOPASSWD` *extremely* carefully, though.

Comment: Sure, don't use that for all commands. Never something like `LOCAL=NOPASSWD: /bin/bash`